# How to reset child view state variable with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm sure it's something very silly but how should one reset the state value of a child view when another state has changed?

For example, the code below shows 2 folders, which respectively have 2 and 3 items., which can be edited.

If you select the second folder (Work) and its 3rd item (Peter) and then select the first folder (Home), the app crashes since `selectedItemIndex` is out of bounds.

I tried to "reset" the state value when the view gets initialized but it seems like changing the state like such triggers out a "runtime: SwiftUI: Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." warning.

```
init(items: Binding<[Item]>) {  
    self._items = items  
    self._selectedItemIndex = State(wrappedValue: 0)  
}
```

What is the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Here's the code:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let store = ItemStore()
        let contentView = ContentView(store: store)

        // Create the window and set the content view. 
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

final class ItemStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Folder] = [Folder(name: "Home",
                                            items: [Item(name: "Mark"), Item(name: "Vincent")]),
                                     Folder(name: "Work",
                                            items:[Item(name: "Joseph"), Item(name: "Phil"), Item(name: "Peter")])]
}

struct Folder: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var content = Date().description
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store: ItemStore
    
    @State var selectedFolderIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        HSplitView {
            // FOLDERS
            List(selection: $selectedFolderIndex) {
                Section(header: Text("Groups")) {
                    ForEach(store.data.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { index, folder in
                        Text(folder.name).tag(index)
                    }
                }.collapsible(false)
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            // ITEMS
            if selectedFolderIndex != nil {
                ItemsView(items: $store.data[selectedFolderIndex!].items)
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 800, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ItemsView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    @State var selectedItemIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        HSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedItemIndex) {
                ForEach(items.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                    Text(item.name).tag(index)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 300)
            
            if selectedItemIndex != nil {
                DetailView(item: $items[selectedItemIndex!])
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(items: Binding<[Item]>) {
        self._items = items
        self._selectedItemIndex = State(wrappedValue: 0)
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $item.name)
        }
    }
}

// Credit: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/03/managing-data-flow-in-swiftui/

struct IndexedCollection<Base: RandomAccessCollection>: RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    typealias Element = (index: Index, element: Base.Element)

    let base: Base

    var startIndex: Index { base.startIndex }

    var endIndex: Index { base.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(after: i)
    }

    func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(before: i)
    }

    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        base.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        (index: position, element: base[position])
    }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func indexed() -> IndexedCollection<Self> {
        IndexedCollection(base: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling derived state in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888328/handling-derived-state-in-swiftui)

Comment: I tried pasting your code into Xcode 11.4 and there quite a few compiler errors, so it's hard to experiment with it. Is there supposed to be a type parameter on IndexedCollection? Something may not have made it into what you pasted into your question. I see `Binding<[Item]>` became `Binding` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@jordanpittman](https://twitter.com/jordanpittman/status/1248006114970501120) for suggesting a fix:

```
ItemsView(items: $store.data[selectedFolderIndex!].items).id(selectedRowIndex)
```

Source: https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id

Answer (score 1):

Fully playable sample draft for `ContentView.swift`. Play with it in both edit modes (inactive/active row selection) and adopt to your needs.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemStore {
    var data: [Folder] = [Folder(name: "Home", items: [Item(name: "Mark"), Item(name: "Vincent")]),
                          Folder(name: "Work", items:[Item(name: "Joseph"), Item(name: "Phil"), Item(name: "Peter")])]
}

struct Folder: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Identifiable {

    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var content = Date().description

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var store: ItemStore

    @State var selectedFolderIndex: Int? = 0
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // FOLDERS

                List(selection: $selectedFolderIndex) {
                    Section(header: Text("Groups")) {
                        ForEach(store.data.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { index, folder in
                            HStack {
                                Text(folder.name).tag(index)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                                .background(Color.white) //make the whole row tapable, not just the text
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedFolderIndex = index
                            }
                        }.onDelete(perform: delete)
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .id(selectedFolderIndex)
                // ITEMS
                if selectedFolderIndex != nil && (($store.data.wrappedValue.startIndex..<$store.data.wrappedValue.endIndex).contains(selectedFolderIndex!) ){
                    ItemsView(items: $store.data[selectedFolderIndex!].items)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        $store.wrappedValue.data.remove(atOffsets: offsets) // Note projected value! `store.data.remove() will not modify SwiftUI on changes and it will crash because of invalid index.
    }
}


struct ItemsView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    @State var selectedDetailIndex: Int?
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            List(selection: $selectedDetailIndex) {
                ForEach(items.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                    Text(item.name).tag(index)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedDetailIndex = index
                    }
                }

            }

            if selectedDetailIndex != nil && (($items.wrappedValue.startIndex..<$items.wrappedValue.endIndex).contains(selectedDetailIndex!) )    {
                DetailView(item: $items[selectedDetailIndex!])
                    .padding()
            }
        }

    }

}


struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $item.name)
        }
    }
}

// Credit: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/03/managing-data-flow-in-swiftui/

struct IndexedCollection<Base: RandomAccessCollection>: RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    typealias Element = (index: Index, element: Base.Element)

    let base: Base

    var startIndex: Index { base.startIndex }

    var endIndex: Index { base.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(after: i)
    }

    func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(before: i)
    }

    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        base.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        (index: position, element: base[position])
    }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func indexed() -> IndexedCollection<Self> {
        IndexedCollection(base: self)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(store: ItemStore())
    }
}
```