# Views observing a Core Data object are not updating

Tags: swiftui

I have a Core Data object called `Config` on `ContentView`.

This object is created like this:

```
@ObservedObject private var config = Config.with(PersistenceController.shared.context)!
```

`config` has 3 boolean properties: `turnedOn`, `isSoft`, and `willAppear`.

`turnedON` and `willAppear` are created in a way that if `turnedON` is `true`, `willAppear` must be `false` and vice-versa.

Now I pass `config` to 3 toggle switches and let the user adjust each one, true or false, but remember, if the user turns `turnedON` `true`, `willAppear` must be `false` and vice-versa. The same is true if the user turns `willAppear` `true`, in that canse `turnedON` must switch to `false` and vice-versa too.

So I pass config to the toggle switches like this on `ContentView`:

```
CustomToggle("Turn it on?"),
             config,
             coreDataBooleanPropertyName:"turnedOn")

CustomToggle("Is it soft?"),
             config,
             coreDataBooleanPropertyName:"isSoft")

CustomToggle("Will it appear?"),
             config,
             coreDataBooleanPropertyName:"willAppear")
```

and this is `CustomToggle`...

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

```
struct CustomToggle: View {
  @State private var status:Bool
  
  private let title: String
  private let coreDataBooleanPropertyName:String
  @ObservedObject private var config:Config {
    didSet {
      switch coreDataBooleanPropertyName {
      case "isSoft":
        self.status = config.isSoft
      case "turnedOn":
        self.status = config.turnedOn
      case "willAppear":
        self.status = config.willAppear
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
  
  init(_ title:String,
       _ config:Config,
       coreDataBooleanPropertyName:String) {
    self.title = title
    self.config = config
    self.coreDataBooleanPropertyName = coreDataBooleanPropertyName
    self.status = defaultStatus
    
    switch coreDataBooleanPropertyName {
    case "isSoft":
      self.status = config.isSoft
    case "turnedOn":
      self.status = config.turnedOn
    case "willAppear":
      self.status = config.willAppear
    default:
      break
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
      Toggle(isOn: $status, label: {
        ControlTitle(title)
      })
        .toggleStyle(CheckboxStyle())
        .onChange(of: status, perform: { newStatus in          
          switch coreDataBooleanPropertyName {
          case "isSoft":
            config.isSoft = newStatus
          case "turnedOn":
            config.turnedOn = newStatus
            config.willAppear = !newStatus
          case "willAppear":
            config.willAppear = newStatus
            config.turnedOn = !newStatus
          default:
            return
          }
          
          let coreDataContext = PersistenceController.shared.context

          do {
            try coreDataContext.save()
          }
          catch let error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
          }
          
        })


struct CheckboxStyle: ToggleStyle {
  
  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    
    return HStack {
      
      Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
        .foregroundColor(configuration.isOn ?  Color.from("ffba00") : .gray)
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
        .onTapGesture {
          configuration.isOn.toggle()
        }
      configuration.label

      Spacer()
    }
    
  }
}
```

I have tested the core data entry `config` and it works properly but the toggle switches `willAppear` and `turnedOn` do not update when one or the other are selected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Property observers don't work on state objects (`@State`, `@ObservedObject`, etc.). You have to use `.onChange)_`.

Comment: what do you mean? Core Data objects are, by default, Observable Objects. Care to explain?

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57486407/7129318)

Comment: sorry but I do not understand how to use that on my code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are already using one `.onChange(of:)` in your code. What exactly don't you understand about it? Also, one more thing, when you initially create your `config`, it should be an `@StateObject`, not an `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: Making it a @StateObject does not solve it. Your answer is too vague. If you want to make it a detailed answer on how my code should be written, I appreciate. If not, thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you expecting your `didSet` to fire when you change a property on `Config` like `isSoft`?

Comment: this is me trying to make it work

Comment: I'm trying to understand the circumstances  you want that code to run so that I can provide an answer. Is the scenario that I mentioned the one in which you're expecting `didSet` to fire?

Comment: yes, but I suppose this can be done using another way. The core data entity is updating correctly according to the switches' values. The problem is the switches not updating when core data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `didSet`, which will not fire if just a property of your object changes, you could observe its changes via `objectWillChange` (note inline comments as well):

```
Toggle(isOn: $status, label: {
        ControlTitle(title)
    })
    .onReceive(config.objectWillChange) { _ in
        //run the code from your didSet here
        //note that you *may* need to use something like DispatchQueue.main.async { } in here to get the updated values of the object since the values may not be updated until the next run loop -- I'm unsure of how this will behave with CoreData objects
    }
    .onChange(of: status, perform: { newStatus in
        //etc
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, was the `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` necessary or does it work without it?

Comment: what dispatchQueue?

Comment: In my answer, there's an inline comment about it possibly being necessary, but I'm guessing this means it was not.